# Confused about the generic which extends an exist Enum type

Tags: java, generics, interface, enums, type-erasure

**QUESTION 1**: I am a bit confused about these codes:

```
public class MyClass1 <E extends Enum<?>> {
    // ...
}
public class MyClass2 <E extends Enum<E>> {
    // ... 
}
```

What is the different between `MyClass1` and `MyClass2`, and what do the three different `E` mean?

**QUESTION 2**: From [`Class Enum <E extends Enum<E>>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html)

> This is the common base class of all Java language enumeration types.

But isn't the common base class of all Enum type `Enum<E>`?

**QUESTION 3**: right now I have this class:

```
public class MyClass<E extends Enum<E>> {

    // for example, EnumSet<Category> 
    public Set<E> category; 

    // how to initial this member
    private Class<E> enumType; 

    // initial this.category with given strings
    public void getEnumSetFromStringList(List<String> list) {
        this.category = EnumSet.noneOf(enumType);
        for (String str : list) {
            this.category.add(Enum.valueOf(this.enumType, str));
        }
    }
}

// this is the Category of Enum type
public enum Category {

    LOCATION("LOCATION"), 
    HUMAN("HUMAN"),
    // ...
    DESCRIPTION("DESCRIPTION");

    private final String categoryName;

    Category(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName= categoryName;
    }
}
```

1. How could I initial the data field `enumType` in `MyClass`?
2. If `MyClass` does not contain the data field `enumType`, how could the function `getEnumSetFromStringList(List<String> list)` get the type of the generic type `<E extends Enum<?>>`?
3. Can I get the Enum type in this way: `E.class`? If not, is it reason from the ***type-erasure*** of generic type during compile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Enum<E extends Enum<E>>` is very difficult to understand.

Let's consider two `enums`.

`enum Colour { RED, GREEN, BLUE }`

`enum Shape { SQUARE, CIRCLE, TRIANGLE }`

Think about the `compareTo()` method in `Enum`. This is used to compare different constants in the same `Enum` based on the order they are declared in. If `Enum` were not a generic class, the signature for this method would have to be `int compareTo(Enum e)`. But that wouldn't make any sense because then you could compare a `Colour` to a `Shape`. We want the signature of `compareTo` in `Colour` to be `int compareTo(Colour colour)`. The only way to do that is if `Enum` is a generic class with a type paramter `E` and the type parameter for `Colour` is `Colour`! As long as the type parameter of `Colour` is `Colour` and the type parameter of `Shape` is `Shape` then we can only compare `Colour`s to `Colour`s and `Shape`s to `Shape`s.

So in the definition of `Enum` we want some way of expressing that, for every subclass, the type parameter must not only be an `enum` but the type parameter should be the subclass itself. Therefore `E` should not just extend `Enum` but `E` should extend `Enum<E>`!

This is where `Enum<E extends Enum<E>>` comes from.

(You should not write `Enum<E extends Enum<?>>`).

One way to assign a value to `enumType` is to pass a `Class<E>` to the constructor. Like this

```
class MyClass2<E extends Enum<E>> {
    private final Class<E> enumType;

    MyClass2(Class<E> enumType) {
        this.enumType = enumType;
    }
}
```

If you don't want to do that, another way to get the `Class<E>` object at runtime is to use the `Enum` instance method `getDeclaringClass()`. This requires you to have an instance of `E` at hand to call the method on though. One way of getting an array of all enum constants at runtime is to write `e.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants()`.

You cannot write `E.class` because, as you rightly say, generics are implemented using the process of type erasure. At runtime, an `ArrayList<String>` is just an `ArrayList`, so it is impossible to access the type parameter.

Comment: So the second `E` in `Enum<E extends Enum<E>>` specifies the basic type which is a Enum type of `E`, and the first `E` acts as the name of generic type name? Another question is that, since an Enum type could not have subclass, the `Enum<E extends Enum<E>>` only represent the Enum class `Category` only extends itself when passing to generic type?

Answer (score 3):

> What is the different between MyClass1 and MyClass2, and what do the three different E mean?

`MyClass1` introduces a generic type parameter, called `E`, which extends the `Enum<?>` class. Here, the `?` means that we don't know (and care) which generic *version* of the `Enum` class does the `E` extend, so a wildcard is used.

Meanwhile, `MyClass2` also introduces a generic type parameter, called `E`, which again extends the `Enum` type. This time, the `Enum` type is generic by **the same** `E`, which means that this type parameter will have to be a subclass of the `Enum` class and will also support all the methods, defined in `Enum`, which use the exact same type `E`. For example, such method is `getDeclaringClass()`, which will return `Class<E>` instead of `Class<Object>`.

---

> But isn't the common base class of all Enum type Enum?

No. The generic parameter won't make sense if it's not a subclass of `Enum<E>`.

---

> How could I initialize the data field enumType in MyClass?

You have to pass the `Class<E>` in the constructor and copy the value to the private member:

```
public MyClass(Class<E> enumType) {
    this.enumType = enumType;
}
```

---

> If MyClass does not contain the data field enumType, how could the function getEnumSetFromStringList(...) get the type of the generic type?

It won't be able to get it, due to the type-erasure. If you need the class of the generic type, you will have to maintain a member, which holds the `Class<E>` value;

---

> Can I get the Enum type in this way: E.class? If not, is it reason from the type-erasure of generic type during compile?

You can't because `E` is just an alias of something that will be *specific* at Runtime.

Comment: And if the `MyClass<E extends Enum<E>>` need to implement the `Serializable` interface, I need to deal with the `public Set<E> category` and the `private Class<E> enumType`. For `category`, I may treat it `Set<String> categoryStringSet = new HashSet<String>(); for (E e : this.category) { categoryStringSet.add(e.name());} writeObject(categoryStringSet);`. And how to serialize `enumType`? And is this a good idea to serialize a class with Enum type inside?

Comment: As far as I can see, `Class` is `Serializable`, so you can just pass it to `writeObject()`.